# Which module in a Linux distribution is responsible for keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-event

I have a specific problem with keyboard shortcuts and haven't gotten a solution for it so far, so now i need to know which module within a Linux distribution is responsible for handling keyboard shortcuts.

By handling keyboard shortcuts, I mean, listening to the key pressing\releasing events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends: on the Linux console, the responsible ***"module"*** is the kernel. In X, the X server interprets the underlying keyboard events and passes some of those on to clients as key press and release events.

That is as far as it goes.  In a terminal emulator, applications do not read *events* (unless they open a special connection to the console).  They read *characters*.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to configure way the X server to handle keyboard shortcuts in an on-release manner rather than on-press ? X server on most distributions handle keyboard shortcuts in an on-press manner.

Comment: That sort of thing is done at the application level (applications interpret events). `xmodmap` is an application, as would be your window manager.

Comment: By "applications", do you also mean an arbitrary desktop application like a browser ? If that's so, then why when I use the same application on different distros, keyboard shortcuts are handled when they are pressed, while on other distros, keyboard shortcuts are handled when they are released ?

Comment: yes: **any** X client can interpret key events in a different way.  Some applications (such as a window manager) get those first and can prevent others from using a given combination.

Comment: I tested the output of `wmctrl -m` that shows the window manager on LMDE (Linux mint, Debian edition) and Linux mint Ubuntu edition and they both had the same output. Yet both handle keyboard shortcuts differently. Debian first a keyboard shortcut on-press, while Ubuntu handles it on-release.

Probably the window manager isn't the responsible module ?

Comment: `wmctrl -m` only shows a small part of the window manager (see [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html), which is what `wmctrl` deals with).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44938/discussion-between-muhammad-gelbana-and-thomas-dickey).